# How to modify ASP.NET_SessionId in a webservice on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session-cookies

I have 2 ASP.NET web application app1&app2.  And I want to use a same ASP.NET_SessionId for a call like this:
Client(Call Login) -> App1(Call App2.Login) -> App2

I found that the app1 sometime can return to client with a same ASP.NET_SessionId as app2 return to app1. But sometimes app1 can't. Can I manually modify the ASP.NET_SessionId in a webservice call on server app1?
Code like:

```
// In app1, for client to call.
[WebMethod]
public string Login(string strName, string strPass)
{
    // Call app2 webservice.
    string strSessionFromApp2 = App2.WebCall();
    // How can I write code to complete this??
    Response.Session[ASP.NET_SessionId] = strSessionFromApp2; 
}
```

Acturally I can modify the client code to use the ASP.NET_SessionId, but this is a lot of work. Here is a wierd thing, when I build app1&app2 in the package machine, they would generate the same ASP.NET_SessionId for the code I mentioned without modifing the ASP.NET_SessionId manually. But when I build the app1&app2 seperately, the would generate different ASP.NET_SessionId in the process I mentioned above. Is there an explaination?

Comment: It's not possible to do that as Session IDs are not controlled by application and they can't be modified in your code.

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is no workaround. You need to carefully design your deployments. If App2 is a sub-folder of App1 and utilizes same web.config, then the chances are high that you will reach to your desired solution.

Comment: Acturally I can modify the client code to use the ASP.NET_SessionId, but this is a lot of work. Here is a wierd thing, when I build app1&app2 in the package machine, they would generate the same ASP.NET_SessionId for the code I mentioned without modifing the ASP.NET_SessionId manually. But when I build the app1&app2 seperately, the would generate different ASP.NET_SessionId in the process I mentioned above.

Comment: I would use something else, not the session. Let's say a common database/table where app1 writes sessionid into, the code passes this sessionid to app2, app2 reads from the database for check the existense and do what to be done.